# key_load_public: No such file or directory while connecting to ssh

Tags: ubuntu, sshd

I have a Windows 10 PC that I want to connect to and use its Internet connection.

So I have installed `openssh` and have it running. When I use `ssh <username>@<pcname>`, I get an error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

And if I use `ssh -v <usrename>@<PCname>`, I get this log:

```
 ~:$ ssh -v senaps@192.168.1.100
 OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 [192.168.1.100] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
 ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

It seems like I don't have these files, but how to get them?
Here is a `ls` on my directory:

```
 ~:$ ls -a .ssh
 .  ..  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

How should I fix this problem? (Guess I don't have access to my PC and want to send my traffic over my PC network rather than the public network I'm in.)

here is a `-vvv` log:

```
~:$ ssh -vvv senaps@192.168.1.100
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.100" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.100 [192.168.1.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/senaps/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

and a log from `tail -500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'` :

```
Sep 22 08:23:29 SenapssPC sshd[2853]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Sep 22 08:23:29 SenapssPC sshd[2853]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 22 08:23:29 SenapssPC sshd[2853]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep 22 19:41:29 SenapssPC sudo:   senaps : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/senaps ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Sep 22 19:42:02 SenapssPC sudo:   senaps : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/senaps ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: The reset is not related to what key files you do or do not have; those messages are only informative.  As expected, ssh is loading your `id_rsa` and not finding any other key files.

Comment: so how do i create all the other files? how should i fix the reset problem? i want my problem solved which one should i follow??? the reset or the files missing ?

Comment: The missing key files are no issue here. Can you run `ssh -vvv ...` for more debug output? It would also help if you could look at the log files of the server or run the server in debug mode and look at its output.

Comment: You might also check the firewall on your Windows host. By default it most likely will not permit SSH connections to port  22.

Comment: nah i have allowed port 22 and openssh on my windows system.

Comment: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` means either that some firewall software is interfering with these connection attempts, or else the ssh server program is malfunctioning (e.g. crashing as soon as it receives the connection). You need to troubleshoot this on the server, not the client.

Comment: @user4556274, how are you deducing that `ssh is loading your id_rsa and not finding any other key files`?  This doesn't seem to be indicated in the verbose output.  I'm trying to diagnose the same issue and struggling with why it's telling me a file doesn't exist when it definitely does.

Comment: @Mark, the `type %d` indicates whether or not the key was successfully found and loaded.  Negative one shows failure, while non-negative integers show success (`0` for RSA (deprecated format), `1` for RSA, `2` for DSA, ...).  In the above snippets, id_rsa is the only key shown with a value other than `-1`.  Not surprisingly given its name, it parsed as an RSA key :-), type `1`.